# How to Enable SSO for AD users on multiple azure portal account

Tags: azure, active-directory, azureportal

I have a situation where I have 2 (portal-account-1 & portal-account-2)Azure portal account and their AD users.

```
Can I authenticate portal-account2 AD user with portal-account1 AD application?
```

OR

```
Can I authenticate AD User of both Portals(portal-account1 & portal-account2)  to each other like we first check on Account1's user and if not found we will look in account2?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Multi tenant  option is the one that you require. Various tenants can access your application on azure irrespective of the azure AD they use.

You need to setup the application as Multi tenant.

All requests must be sent to  /common endpoint.

code changes must be done to handle multiple tenants.

azure documentation -->

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview

Sample -->

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect/

Comment: Thanks. It means my portal-account-2 active directory users can access apps inside the portal-account-1?

Comment: Yes,If the multi tenant setup and configuration are done to allow those directories which are tenants to your application.

Comment: Hey @Aravind Here I am talking about two different accounts of azure portal not about multiple directory in single account

Comment: @BipinJain I updated the AAD multi tenant link. Yes it will work for users from same AD or different Azure AD .

Comment: But same user needs to be in both different AD OR different Azure AD?

Comment: any user in any AD. as long as the AD is part of the multi tenant setup it will work.